# Sending a Multipart/form-data POST With JSON File in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to send a multipart form with Kotlin in Android Studio:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
{ 
....
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        uploadPost()
    }
....
}

fun uploadPost() {
    var theJSON = ClockinJSON("a person", "a time", "example@example.com")
    var myFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/example.json")
    var value = theJSON.toString()
    myFile.writeText(value)
    var jsonFileBody: RequestBody = myFile.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())

    var pdfFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "/Hello.pdf")
    var pdfBody = pdfFile.asRequestBody("multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull())

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    var service = retrofit.create(UploadFile::class.java)
    val call = service.uploadFile(pdfBody, jsonFileBody)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
            Log.d("TRACE", "response is$response")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("TRACE", "didn't work$t")
            call.cancel()
        }
    })
}

data class ClockinJSON (
    var clockinTime: String,
    var location: String,
    var companyEmail: String
)

interface UploadFile {
@Multipart
@POST("mail/")
fun uploadFile(
    @Part("report") report: RequestBody,
    @Part("json") json: RequestBody
): Call<String>
}
```

Right now I am getting error 500 on the POST request and the server is setup correctly; My Typescript app is sending just fine. I followed the documentation the best I could, and went through all the examples that I can find. Can anyone take a look at let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please check your base URL is correct or not.

Comment: its good sir. checks out.

Comment: Did you check this request in postman ?